# Input and output do not stay within box boundaries

Tags: html, css

I am VERY new to `CSS` and I am trying to create a chatbot in which I can ask chatGPT (downloaded locally) questions about code and I have an issue that I can't find a solution to.

I cannot, whatever I do, find a way for the response to stay within the boundaries of the response box I have created. The response is returned as one single line and exists the boundaries of the box.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="light dark" style="color-scheme: light dark">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="highlight/styles/default.css">
    <title>Code generator</title>
<style>
    body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #chat-container {
        width: 60%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        padding: 20px;
        word-break: break-all;
    }
    #text-section {
        width: 40%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 20px;
        word-break: break-all;
    }
    #user-input {
        width: 100%;
        height: 80px;
        resize: vertical;
    }
    #chat-history {
    word-break: break-all;
    }
    code {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: #333;
        display: block;
        font-family: monospace;
        font-size: 14px;
        margin: 10px 0;
        padding: 10px;
    }
     .banner {
        background-color: #333;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: bold;
        height: 50px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0 20px;
    }
</style>


</head>

<body>

    <div id="chat-container">
        <img src="pricerim.png">
        <h1>Code generator: chatGPT based</h1>
        <div id="chat-history"></div>
        <form id="chat-form">
            <input type="text" id="user-input" placeholder="What can I help you with?">
            <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="text-section">
        <h2>Usage and disclaimer</h2>
        <p>.....</p>

        <p>.....</p>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#chat-form').submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var userInput = $('#user-input').val();
                $('#chat-history').append('<p>You: ' + userInput + '</p>');
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/get_response',
                    data: {user_input: userInput},
                    success: function(response) {
                        var formattedResponse = '<code>' + response.replace(/\n/g, '<br>') + '</code>';
                        $('#chat-history').append(formattedResponse);
                        $('#user-input').val('');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
<script src="highlight/highlight.pack.js"></script>
    <script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using textarea instead of the input tag like this:

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#chat-container {
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 20px;
    word-break: break-all;
}
#text-section {
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    word-break: break-all;
}
#user-input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    resize: vertical;
}
#chat-history {
word-break: break-all;
}
code {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 10px;
}
 .banner {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="chat-container">
        <img src="pricerim.png">
        <h1>Code generator: chatGPT based</h1>
        <div id="chat-history"></div>
        <form id="chat-form">
            <textarea id="user-input" placeholder="What can I help you with?"></textarea>
            <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="text-section">
        <h2>Usage and disclaimer</h2>
        <p>.....</p>

        <p>.....</p>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#chat-form').submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var userInput = $('#user-input').val();
                $('#chat-history').append('<p>You: ' + userInput + '</p>');
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/get_response',
                    data: {user_input: userInput},
                    success: function(response) {
                        var formattedResponse = '<code>' + response.replace(/\n/g, '<br>') + '</code>';
                        $('#chat-history').append(formattedResponse);
                        $('#user-input').val('');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: This work perfectly for the input box, but the response is still as a one line. So, there is not line break at th end of the response box.

Comment: If you press enter in textarea, it will show the line break. And the size of the box will change depending on screen-size. Do you want to automate line breaks?